# create a numpy array from data on a row

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

My data file has a sample for each row.
Each row is 400 float number. It's a 20x20 image on a single line. 
I have to write a numpy array with dimensions (number of row, 20, 20, 1).
Last dimension is the value (the float number in the file).

I tried something like:

```
X1=[]
for x in range (1,nrow+1):
    for a in range (1,21):
        for b in range (1,21):
           index = a*b-1
           X1.append((x,a,b,X[x,index]))
X = np.array(X1)
```

but I know this is wrong.

EDIT:

Maybe this is the solution:

```
X1=[]
for x in range (1,Nsamples+1):
    for a in range (1,21):
        for b in range (1,21):
           index = a*b-1
           X1.append((X[x,index]))
           #X1.append((X[x,index], x))
X = np.array(X1)
X = X.reshape(Nsamples,20,20,1)
```

Comment: If you know this is wrong? Why do you think that? Please provide any exception you encountered while running the code? Also what is nrow

Comment: I know it's wrong because with one row the shape of the X array is (400, 4) and i would like to get (1,20,20,1). 
nrow is the number of row in the file. 
Each row is 400 float number.

Comment: so `nrow=400` ?

Comment: No. Sorry but I am a beginner. 
nrow is not fixed. Presently it's 1 just for testing, 
Each row has 400 float number that should go in a 20x20 matrix.

Comment: If the dimensions have to include the "number of row", that means the dimension is variable, since there are 20 rows, each with a different number. So I'm unclear what your actual intention is. Perhaps it should be "number*s* of row*s*"?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Dimensions is "numbers of rows". 
With 1 row I need an array shape: (1,20,20,1) where first 1 is the row number

Comment: Why Nx20x20x1 instead of just Nx20x20? Unless you have a particular broadcasting in mind, unit dimensions are usually pointless.

Comment: I believe the four dimensions are necessary as input for conv2D in keras, but I might be wrong

Comment: What is the type of `X`? Also a numpy array?

Comment: Yes. It comes from
dataset = np.loadtxt("input.dat", delimiter=",")
X = dataset[:,0:400]

Answer (score 1):

try using reshape

```
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0],20,20,1)
```

it will give you a numpy array of reshaped images with same number of lines

Comment: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1600 into shape (400,20,20,1).

Comment: X.shape[0] is 400

Comment: what is X.shape ?

Comment: X.shape is (400, 4) so I can't reshape to (1,20,20,1)

Comment: your 400 floats are in a column not in a row

Comment: X.shape[1] works, but the result is not what I need.

Comment: you want a 4 rows of your 400 pixel images becoming a (20x20x1) images right ?

Comment: 4 is wrong, it comes from: ((x,a,b,X[x,index]))
I want one row in a 20x20x1 images, right

Comment: so from a (400,4) array you want to only take the (400,first) image ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the correct answer, thanks to people who helped.

```
X1=[]
for x in range (1,Nsamples+1):
    for a in range (1,21):
        for b in range (1,21):
           index = a*b-1
           X1.append((X[x,index]))
X = np.array(X1)
X = X.reshape(Nsamples,20,20,1)
```